# How to modify shared objects using foreach loop in R?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I am trying to speed up the for-loop by converting it into for-each loop in parallel. However, it incurs some problems when it needs to modify some shared objects. A toy example can be as follow.

```r
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 4)
a <- c()
b <- c()
foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
  a <- c(a, i)
  b <- c(b, i^2)
  NULL  # to take up a place for the return statement
}
a
b
```

Ideally, I would like the vector `a` to be `c(1, 2, 3, ..., 100)`, and `b` to be `c(1, 4, 9, ..., 10000)`, where order of elements doesn't matter. However, the result from the above code snippet is vector `a` and vector `b` are both being empty.

Anyone has an idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Thanks!

-- Edit --
To give you a little bit more context, I am trying to parallelize a BFS algorithm in R. A skeleton of the code looks like the following:

```r
q <- queue()
s <- set()
l <- list(...)
while(length(q) > 0){
  element <- pop(q)
  for(edge connect to element){
    if(!s contains edge && some other conditions){
      s <- set_union(s, <something new>)
      pushback(q, <something new>)
      l[[1]] <- <something new>
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to convert the inner for-loop to a foreach loop that can spread the computations for these edges to different cores. However, the data structures set, queue, and list are shared. If there is no simple way to acquire locks on them, do they have any corresponding concurrent data structures, like the ConcurrentHashMap for HashMap in Java?

Comment: In my real code, I will be modifying a list, a queue, and a set in the foreach loop. If there is no quick fix to the above code, some suggestions on their corresponding concurrent data structures also help. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it's simply not possible. You'll have to write a loop without side effects if you want to use parallel computing. Study the foreach package vignette.

Comment: @Roland: Since I am trying to learn parallel computing: If you would be so  kind to point it out for me: Where is the 'side effect' "happening" in the code example?

Comment: The side effect is subset-assignment into objects outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what the OP is after but it returns a data.frame with two vectors as expected:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 4)
result <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  a <- i
  b <- i^2
  data.frame(a, b)
}
result
```

> ```
>     a   b
> 1   1   1
> 2   2   4
> 3   3   9
> 4   4  16
> 5   5  25
> 6   6  36
> 7   7  49
> 8   8  64
> 9   9  81
> 10 10 100
> ```

Note that I have reduced the number of iterations to 10 for demonstration.